# The application does not work on newer versions of Android (version 9 and above)

Tags: java, android, audio, ringtone, ringtonemanager

This application sets the tones, but it stops working in storing the tone on the newer versions and works efficiently on the old versions. I would like your help to solve the problem

I think the storage path has been changed for the latest versions

I've tried and searched a lot and can't find a solution to this problem

**This is the code**

```
private void requestPermission () {

    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale ( this , android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE )) {
        Intent intent = new Intent ( );
        intent.setAction ( Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS );
        Uri uri = Uri.fromParts ( "package" , getPackageName ( ) , null );
        intent.setData ( uri );
        startActivity ( intent );
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions ( this , new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE} , REQUEST_CODE );
    }
}

@SuppressLint("ObsoleteSdkInt")
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult ( int requestCode , @NonNull String[] permissions , @NonNull int[] grantResults ) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult ( requestCode , permissions , grantResults );
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[ 0 ] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                if (! Settings.System.canWrite ( this )) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent ( Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION )
                            .setData ( Uri.parse ( "package:" + getPackageName ( ) ) )
                            .addFlags ( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK );
                    startActivity ( intent );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


@SuppressLint("Recycle")
private void set_tone ( String N1 , String N2 ) {
    AssetFileDescriptor openAssetFileDescriptor;
    (( AudioManager ) getSystemService ( AUDIO_SERVICE )).setRingerMode ( 2 );
    File file = new File ( Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory ( Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC ) + "/AndRody" , N2 );
    if (! file.getParentFile ( ).exists ( )) {

        file.getParentFile ( ).mkdirs ( );

    }
    if (! file.exists ( )) {
        try {
            file.createNewFile ( );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace ( );
        }
    }
    Uri parse = Uri.parse ( "android.resource://" + getPackageName ( ) + "/raw/" + N2 );
    ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver ( );
    try {
        openAssetFileDescriptor = contentResolver.openAssetFileDescriptor ( parse , "r" );
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e2) {
        openAssetFileDescriptor = null;
    }
    try {
        byte[] bArr = new byte[1024];
        assert openAssetFileDescriptor != null;
        FileInputStream createInputStream = openAssetFileDescriptor.createInputStream ( );
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream ( file );
        for (int read = createInputStream.read ( bArr ); read != - 1; read = createInputStream.read ( bArr )) {
            fileOutputStream.write ( bArr , 0 , read );
        }
        fileOutputStream.close ( );
    } catch (IOException e3) {
        e3.printStackTrace ( );
    }

    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues ( );
    contentValues.put ( "_data" , file.getAbsolutePath ( ) );
    contentValues.put ( "title" , N1 );
    contentValues.put ( "mime_type" , "audio/mpeg" );
    contentValues.put ( "_size" , file.length () );
    contentValues.put ( "is_ringtone" , Boolean.TRUE );

    try {
        Toast.makeText ( this , new StringBuilder ( ).append ( "تم تعيين النغمة بنجاح" ) , Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show ( );
        RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri ( getBaseContext ( ) , 1, contentResolver.insert ( MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath ( file.getAbsolutePath ( ) ) , contentValues ) );
    } catch (Throwable th) {
        Toast.makeText ( this , new StringBuilder ( ).append ( "يوجد خلل ما" ) , Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show ( );
    }


}
```

I think the change should be in this code

```
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues ( );
contentValues.put ( "_data" , file.getAbsolutePath ( ) );
contentValues.put ( "title" , N1 );
contentValues.put ( "mime_type" , "audio/mpeg" );
contentValues.put ( "_size" , file.length () );
contentValues.put ( "is_ringtone" , Boolean.TRUE );
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified the codes and it worked for me. This is the solution after the modification

```
 public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 31) {
                    if (!Environment.isExternalStorageManager()) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
                        intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void requestPermission() {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,android. Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
            Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
            intent.setData(uri);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 31) {
                try {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
                    startActivity(intent);
                } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            } else {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,android. Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        }
    }

    private void set_tone(String N1, String N2) {
        AssetFileDescriptor openAssetFileDescriptor;
        ((AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE)).setRingerMode(AudioManager.MODE_RINGTONE);
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/AndRody", N2);
        if (!file.getParentFile().exists()) {
            file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        }
        if (!file.exists()) {
            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        Uri parse = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/" + N2);
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        try (InputStream inputStream = contentResolver.openInputStream (parse );
             OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA, file.getAbsolutePath());
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, N1);
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mpeg");
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.SIZE, file.length());
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);

        try {
            Toast.makeText(this, "تم تعيين النغمة بنجاح", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(getBaseContext(), 1, contentResolver.insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(file.getAbsolutePath()), contentValues));
        } catch (Throwable th) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "يوجد خلل ما", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```